# Model could not be loaded in JOIN

Tags: join, models, phalcon

I am trying to do an inner join within a model static method.

It is my Licenses model:

```
<?php
namespace Gadwin\Models;
use Gadwin\Models\Serials;

class Licenses extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model;
{
    ...

    public static function getFullInformation($id = null)
    {
        $queryBuilder = Licenses::query();
        $queryBuilder->join('Serials', 'Serials.id = Licenses.serial_id');
        $resultset = $queryBuilder->execute();
        var_dump($resultset);
    }
}
```

But, when execute the method, a Phalcon exception is throwed:

> PhalconException: Model 'Serials' could not be loaded

It is my Serials models:

```
class Serials extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    public $id;
    public $build_id;
    public $used;
}
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried the full namespace in the query?

Comment: Yes, and the method works. But, why Phalcon can't autoload the model class ?

Comment: Phalcon tried load model calss on ROOT namespace such as require('\Serials'), so couldn't load it. Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Manager:registerNamespaceAlias() may help you.

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution of this problem ? currently facing same issue. or if you could give me some pointers for reference.